# Return an empty widget with null safety assistance

Tags: flutter, dart

Have been following a tutorial and due to null safety in current version of flutter, I am unable to return anything empty but it is required to return custom page designs dynamically

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BasePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BasePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<BasePage> createState() => BasePageState();
}

class BasePageState<T extends BasePage> extends State<T> {
  bool isApiCallProcess = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(70.0), child: _buildAppBAr()),
      body: ProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: isApiCallProcess,
        opacity: 0.3,
        child: pageUI(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget pageUI() {
  return null;
}

Widget _buildAppBAr() {
  return AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[800],
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    title: const Text(
      'Kem-D Batteries',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
    ),
    actions: const [
      Icon(
        Icons.notifications_none,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.shopping_cart,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

in the

```
Widget pageUI() {
  return null;
}
```

Get runtime error when I null the widget as the `pageUI()` in the child widget can't be assigned to a non-null widget.

I tired `pageUI()!` didn't work, same as

```
Widget pageUI() {
  return null!;
}
```

also didn't work. Any assistance will be appreciated.

I tired `pageUI()!` didn't work, same as

```
Widget pageUI() {
  return null!;
}
```

also didn't work.

I want to display products related to their unique id and the code below is for the display of categories by id

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'base_page.dart';

class ProductPage extends BasePage {
const ProductPage({Key? key, required this.catgeoryId}) :  super(key: key);

final int catgeoryId;

@override
// ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
_ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
 }

class _ProductPageState extends BasePageState<ProductPage> {
@override
Widget pageUI() {
return Container(
  child: Text(
    widget.catgeoryId.toString(),
  ),
 );
 }
}
```

Comment: have you called `pageUI()` within the builder ?

Comment: yes, done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two changes to be made.

```
1. Widget? pageUI() { // make returnType nullable
  return null;
}
```

While calling use `??` operator

```
2. body: ProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: isApiCallProcess,
        opacity: 0.3,
        child: pageUI() ?? Container(), // This is important
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped in the null safety but on the dynamic page, it returns white screen which is the empty container.

Comment: @Nulledf You can replace Container with any widget of your choice.

Comment: Try editing your question and tell us what you exactly need.

Comment: Now you will get the Text() from the pageUI

Comment: No text showing. Still blank

Answer (score 0):

Make the return type of your function nullable using operator `?`, so you can return null.

```dart
Widget? pageUI() {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: tried it as flutters quick fix but the `child: pageUI()` gets error with `The argument type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can return**

```
return const SizedBox.shrink();
```

Comment: learnt something new here. Thank you but does not return the anything but white blank screen.

Comment: if you want to return pageUI from ProductPage do as follow: `Widget pageUI() {
  return ProductPage(catgeoryId:yourCategoryId);
}`

Comment: tried but returning same blank screen.